# Is there an equivalent of Ruby Flip Flop Operator in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Ruby has a 'flip flop' operator, which is like an if statement that returns `true` when a given argument meets the 'start' predicate, and from then on it won't return false until after it evaluates an argument that meets the 'end' predicate.

This article explains more clearly: https://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/

> Let’s take another example that sheds more light on this operator’s behavior. Imagine you’re parsing a file which has markers called `indent` and `dedent` in it. Whenever you encounter a line that contains indent you need to turn ON indentation for all lines after that, and turn it OFF when you come across a line that contains `dedent`.
>
> As an example, this is the text we’re trying to transform:
>
> ```
> zero indentation
> indent
> inside block
> dedent
> after the block
> indent
> another block
> dedent
> end of file
> ```
>
> And this is what the output should look like:
>
> ```
> zero indentation
>   indent
>   inside block
>   dedent
> after the block
>   indent
>   another block
>   dedent
> end of file
> ```
>
> In this case, we would need to keep track of whether or not we’ve turned on indentation. The flip-flop operator does this out of the box for us.
>
> ```rb
> lines = File.readlines('somefile')
>
> lines.each do |line|
>   if line =~ /^indent/ .. line =~ /^dedent/
>     puts " " + line
>   else
>     puts line
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> Now the operator starts looking a bit more useful. You could read this as: starting from the lines containing `indent`, until you encounter `dedent`, add two spaces at the start of the line.

Is there an equivalent in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in equivalent in Kotlin. However, you can create your own version.

There are three things to remember

- It needs some way of storing state.
- The start and end predicates need to be different
- The range is inclusive, so when an element doesn't match the end, it's the *next* element that is considered 'out of range'.

To make the code more succinct, I have used [`operator fun contains(...)`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#in-operator)

```kotlin
/**
 * A ranged flip/flop switch.
 *
 * [contains] will return `false` until it receives an element that matches [start].
 * [contains] will then return `true`, until [end] matched a _previous_ element.
 *
 * @param[start] The inclusive start of the range
 * @param[end] The inclusive end of the range
 */
class FlipFlopSwitch<E>(
  initialState: Boolean = false,
  val start: (E) -> Boolean,
  val end: (E) -> Boolean,
) {
  var switch: Boolean = initialState
    private set

  operator fun contains(element: E): Boolean {
    return if (switch) {
      // element is in the inclusive range,
      // and check to see if the next element isn't
      switch = !end(element)
      true
    } else {
      // currently not inside of the range,
      // check to see if element matches the start
      switch = start(element)
      switch
    }
  }
}
```

Example usage ([Kotlin Playground runnable example](https://pl.kotl.in/jjc_3ysL1))

```kotlin
fun main() {

  val input = """
    zero indentation
    indent
    inside block
    dedent
    after the block
    indent
    another block
    dedent
    end of file
  """.trimIndent()

  // the switch should be active between 'indent' and 'dedent' (inclusive)
  val indentSwitch = FlipFlopSwitch<String>(
    start = { it.startsWith("indent") },
    end = { it.startsWith("dedent") },
  )

  val parsed = input.lines().joinToString("\n") { line ->
    if (line in indentSwitch) {
      line.prependIndent("  ")
    } else {
      line
    }
  }

  println(parsed)
}
```